# Converting a String into a Constructor to make a new Object

Tags: java, serialization, reflection, type-conversion, deserialization

```
@NotNull
public static String toString(@NotNull Object object, @NotNull Object[] variables, Class<?>... parameters) throws NoSuchMethodException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(object.getClass().getConstructor(parameters)).append('\n');
    sb.append(object.getClass()).append(":");
    for (Object variable : variables){
        sb.append(" | ").append(variable.toString());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

A brief explanation of the code, the toString() method uses an object, the variables of the constructor that the user wants to save, and the parameters of a constructor. This method would form the parameters in a way like this:

```
public User(java.lang.String,int)
class User: | username | 369172
```

I want to use this String format to convert the above into a new instance of the Object that was taken in using the method below:

```
public static Object toObject(@NotNull String formattedObject, @NotNull Object object, Class<?>... parameters){
    // The code I need to figure out.
}
```

I want to figure out: how to get all the variables cast into a form where I could use them to make a new instance of the object if I didn't know how many variables/parameters there are, how to use the method in the event the constructor of the Object is private, and if one of the parameters is an Object that prints out the default Object toString() method. How could I do this?

EDIT: I want to avoid using the Serialization interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are *definitely* reinventing the wheel

- Java Object Serialization already does this, albeit that the serialization format is binary (and opaque).
- Various JSON (or XML) <-> POJO binding mechanisms already do this, albeit that the serialization format can be verbose.

(Now there are limits to what these schemes can do.  For example, they cannot serialize a `Thread` or a `Socket`.  But neither can your proposal ... for the same reasons.   These classes have state that simply cannot be captured in a serialization.)

But if you really want to invent the wheel, you can do it.

- As noted, you can use reflection to access and call a public or private constructor on a non-abstract type.
- There is also an "under the hood" `Unsafe` mechanism that JOS uses to create objects without invoking any constructor.  Combine this with `Unsafe` methods for assigning values to fields.

However, your approach implicitly assumes that the `toString` method returns a string that can be used later to reconstruct the object.  This is not true, in general.

- The default implementation returns a string consisting of the object's class name and its identity hashcode.  (An example of the types affected by this is any array type.)  You can't reconstruct an object from that.
- And even for cases where the `toString` result *does* include the information needed for deserialization, the string format is rarely standardized.  (The `Collection` APIs are the exception ...)

In short, `toString` is not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are kinda reinventing the wheel.

For your question first, you need to know which `User` class you want to deserialize. Your stringified form should look somewhat like this:

```
my.package.name.User(java.lang.String, int)
my.package.name.User: variables...
```

Otherwise, how would you know is it `my.package.User` or `my.package.name.User`? Of course, you could write a custom adapter for this "figuring out" phase to get the full class name but I guess you shouldn't.

```java
// You can directly parse the parameter classes, technically you don't need it
// at method parameter. You can include it if you feel like it's easier to work
// with predefined values.
public Object toObject(String string) throws Exception {
  // get your full class name here first
  // parse it first or whatever 
  String className = getConstructorClass(params1);
  String[] parameterClassName = getConstructorParameterClassNames(params2);
  String[] parameterStringifiedValue = getParameterValues(params3);
  
  Class<?> clz = Class.forName(className);
  @SurpressWarning("unchecked") // List<Class<?>> is the same anyway
  Class[] parameterClasses = // repeat Class.forName()...
  Object[] parameters = // An example, for(int i=...
  // parameterClasses[i]
  //  .getDeclaredConstructor(String.class)
  //  .newInstance(parameterStringifiedValue[i]);
  return clz
    .getDeclaredConstructor(constructorParamClasses)
    .newInstance(parameters);

}
```

This whole parsing is so painful ngl. You probably want to use Java built-in serialization support or parse from a well-supported format (xml, json...) and let libraries do all the intricacies.

You can use generic for as a more type-safe approach, but requires more knowledge from calling context.

```java
public <T> T toObject(Class<T> objectType, String string) {
  return objectType.getDeclaredConstructor(...).newInstance(...);
}
```